# Why CloudFront behavior pattern not working as expected?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-http-api

I have my custom domain being served from s3 bucket via cloudfront which is working fine.
Now I have added another origin which is an endpoint from api gateway that has some routes that I want to access like

> mydomain.com/app/*

What I have done so far is created a Custom Origin which has custom domain which is the url that I get from api gateway after deployment. Please look at the Custom origin settings.
[image]

I have also create a behavior which have pattern like app/* so that every request that comes from there goes to the custom origin that I have defined. Please look at the config for behavior.
[image]

So It **does not** work when I access the app endpoint like

> mydomain.com/app/test

but it does, when I have extra slash like **//app**

> mydomain.com//app/test

what am I missing ? Also this whole setup only works with api gateway if I use Rest Api and does not work with Http endpoint at all. It just keep giving me 404. Will be grateful for any pointers and also if some one can point me to how do I debug or log it, like how do I see what is coming in at cloudfront and what is going out from it. I enabled logs but it only showed what came in not what it becomes after it goes through those behaviors. I enabled logging on gateway side too but those 404's are not getting their either.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Path pattern for the Behavior must have a forward "/":
"/app/*"